# Ripping posts from a facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm an admin for a very active facebook group, and I'm looking to be able to extract the posts as a text file so that I can do statistical analysis on it for a research project.

Honestly, I've never really worked with programatically interacting with facebook, but it seems like it would be a simple query. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisites:

Your group needs to be publicly viewable
You need to have signed up to make a Facebook app, in order to get the APP_ID AND SECRET_KEY.

Then, (example in PHP, but should easily be transposed to another language):

```
$url =
"https://graph.facebook.com/{$group_id}/feed?access_token=APP_ID|SECRET_KEY";

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

$data is just JSON formatted data, that should be easy to parse, especially with probable preexisting JSON helper libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this fb-graph post from my colleague: http://rad.batnag.org/2011/04/ruby-hacking-secrets-from-barney-stinson/ as a starting point.